# Hebrew text of Mishna Berurah

Tags: product-recommendation, mishnah-berurah

I'm looking for hebrew text of the Mishnah Beurah. Where can I find free text of the *mishnah berurah*?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for an online copy, or would you also interested in finding a hard copy?

Comment: @Fred http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231

Comment: @msh210 Seems to me that the last paragraph of the meta answer applies. Anyway, I +1'd your answer given how the question stands.

Answer (score 2):

[The wikisource](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41121) is incomplete. For anything else, there are scanned copies on Hebrewbooks:

MB Chelek 1 http://hebrewbooks.org/14170

MB Chelek 2 http://hebrewbooks.org/14164

MB Chelek 3 http://hebrewbooks.org/14171

MB Chelek 4 http://hebrewbooks.org/40448

MB Chelek 5 http://hebrewbooks.org/14169

MB Chelek 6 http://hebrewbooks.org/14166

Comment: Did not check your links, but you should note in your answer that these ספרים may be read online or downloaded (useful for those who don't always have we access)

Comment: These links are incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

[You can find it in many libraries worldwide.](http://www.worldcat.org/search?qt=worldcat_org_bks&q=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94+%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94&fq=dt%3Abks)

Answer (score 1):

http://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94 This is from wiki text it has alot of texts .

Comment: Note that it's incomplete as of this writing.

Answer (score 1):

A few websites/apps that I know of have the complete text:

1. http://mishnaberura.eu5.org/
2. The [OYW app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oyw.hlc&hl=en) has it.
3. you can access the back end of the above app directly through a web
   browser if you prefer at http://mobile.tora.ws/index.html
4. If you want English, check out the [archives of the Mishnah Yomi](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/archive.php) project.

The first three include the text of the Shulchan aruch and Rema, plus the MB and Beur Halacha, but not any of the other commentaries usually printed in printed editions of the MB. The last one (the English one) includes only the translation of the MB itself, (plus some commentary), but they also have pdf images scanned from a printed book which include all the other commentaries usually printed with the MB.